# Communication between Podio and WebService using hook

Tags: podio

we need to do a communication between Podio and a WebService, and we suppose that the solution is to use hooks.
We have a WebService with one function "createInvoice" with some parameters, and we need to invoke this when we create an item on Podio.
We have read the Podio documentantion but we don't find the manner to do this.

http://podio.github.io/podio-dotnet/webhooks/

As the above link suggests, is it necessary to use a ".ashx" class (Handler) to receive the item from Podio and send the correct information to the WebService or exists another solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to be an ashx file.

You just need to have a public URL that expects POST parameters from Podio.

As given in the example code, you need to check the "type" parameter and verify the webhook to enable it.

Comment: Hi Ansar, thanks for your answer, but which example code are you referring?